# Upgrade Python 2.4 to 2.6 or 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am running Python 2.4 on Redhat Linux 5.

Any idea how to upgrade to either Python 2.6 or 3.0?

Thanks in advance,
Sum

Comment: Download the source code and build it?

Answer (score 2):

1. See before upgrading version is 2.x

   ```
   python --version
   Python 2.7.5
   ```
2. Use below command to upgrade your python to 3.x version-

   **yum install python3x**

   replace **x** with the version number you want.

   i.e. for installing python 3.6 execute

   ```
   yum install python36
   ```
3. After that if you want to set this python for your default version then in **bashrc** file add

   vi ~/.bashrc

   ```
   alias python='python3.6'
   ```
4. execute bash command to apply the settings

   ```
   bash
   ```
5. Now you can see the version below

   ```
   python --version
   Python 3.6.3
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As with all software on Linux, the first port of call should be the package manager, using it will give you a relatively painless experience most of the time.

In the case of Red Hat, that is `yum`, so you probably want something like:

```
yum update python
```

If there is not a package for the software at hand, then you could download the source code and build it, but note that this is generally a harder route - firstly it's more work, and secondly package maintainers are careful to ensure that software functions correctly on a distro, so they are more likely to work well and interact well with the rest of your system.

It's worth noting that you can have 2.x and 3.x installed side-by-side, and most distros package them separately. As such, to get 3.x, you probably want to do:

```
yum install python3
```

(Note I don't use Red Hat, so I don't know for sure that is the correct package name).

As a final point - 2.4, 2.6 and 3.0 are all outdated versions. You really want Python 2.7.2 (the latest 2.x release) or Python 3.3 (the latest 3.x release).

Comment: @sumana You may need to install the package if it isn't already installed (which will depend on how you installed the old version), and you may need to mess with the configuration of your package manager, if it hasn't got any repos set (try `yum repolist` and see if you have any), for example.